# How to upload a photo from an iOS device to AWS S3 in Flutter application?

Tags: ios, amazon-s3, flutter, dart

I have been trying to upload images in **Flutter** application to [AWS S3](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/).

I used this plugin: [amazon_s3_cognito](https://pub.dev/packages/amazon_s3_cognito), it worked correctly with Android device using this method:

```
String uploadedImageUrl = await AmazonS3Cognito.upload(
            _image.path,
            BUCKET_NAME,
            IDENTITY_POOL_ID,
            IMAGE_NAME,
            AwsRegion.US_EAST_1,
            AwsRegion.AP_SOUTHEAST_1);
```

But, when I run the same project on iOS device, the `upload` method returned with an **empty String**!

I tried to edit the source code of the plugin but I got stuck.

Please suggest a solution using this plugin or any solution to upload the image and get its link.

Answer (score -1):

This is a known issue with the plugin, it only works for public buckets for now

https://github.com/prachiFam/amazon_s3_cognito/issues/5

I found this tutorial that is helpfull on how to implement

[Upload & fetch media files from AWS S3 in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53811487/upload-fetch-media-files-from-aws-s3-in-flutter)