# How to upload files to Wasabi from Flutter

Tags: flutter, amazon-s3, wasabi-hot-cloud-storage

I am currently working on an application where I would like to upload videos and images to a Wasabi s3 bucket in Flutter. I first attempted to use [amplify_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/amplify_flutter), but this did not work because as detailed in their setup [guide](https://docs.amplify.aws/start/getting-started/installation/q/integration/flutter#option-1-watch-the-video-guide) I am required to log into Amazon Web Services in order to configure the package.

I did find another stack overflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54983831/15245201) describing how to upload to AWS with an https request. copying this code did give me the ability to connect with https://s3.wasabisys.comm, but when using a POST request to upload the files, the url returns this error message:

```
<Error><Code>MethodNotAllowed</Code><Message>The specified method is not allowed against this 
resource.</Message><RequestId>9E0DDF6269E6C862</RequestId>
<HostId>rLX8KeJ9ZPbk6+Zy+GvXUgG1f8ffJ8cNK92KUBnd8DLruqbWbX7dWyKy37N4IoHtqp41+ctRVEBC</HostId></Error>
```

I did find a [post](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=537248) on the AWS forums describing the same issue, and they stated that a "CloudFront Origin Access Identity" needs to be enabled, but since I am not using CloudFront either, enabling this option is not possible for me.

In Wasabi, is there an option similar to "CloudFront Origin Access Identity" that I can enable in order to allow POST requests to a bucket, or is there a better option in Flutter to upload to Wasabi s3 buckets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update: I was able to solve this by using the [Minio](https://pub.dev/packages/minio) flutter package. We have been using this package for a couple weeks now without any issue to connect to Wasabi.

Comment: thank you for returning here with the answer!