# How to access S3 bucket using Flutter Amplify without authentication from AWS cognito

Tags: flutter, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I've created an S3 bucket and made its access level to public. I don't have AWS Cognito configured with the project. I need to use amplify_storage_s3 to get and put files to the bucket without a cognito userpool. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the official response [here](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-flutter/issues/108#issuecomment-689309725), it does not support.

> currently it's not possible to use S3 plugin without Cognito as it is used to sign the S3 requests. You can enable guest access while configuring Auth through CLI such that your app's users wouldn't have to sign in to use S3 resources (by using the guest access)

But I found a probably workaround [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54983831)